# Capturar click de mouse Mars

Tags: assembly, eventos-do-mouse, mips

Existe algum syscall ou  outro mecanismo que consiga capturar o click do mouse pelo simulador do mips Mars .

Comment: Não há necessidade da pergunta ser repetida no inglês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o link da lista de "syscall" que foram implementadas pelos professores que criaram o MARS.

https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html

Infelizmente só é possível interagir com o MARS através do teclado, analisando o código fonte do mesmo nunca vi outra possibilidade.